# Curry-Howard isomorphism: What is the logical counterpart of closure conversion?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, type-theory

Continuation-Passing Style (CPS) translation in programming languages corresponds to double-negation translation in logic (and the Yoneda lemma in category theory). Then what in logic corresponds to closure conversion in programming languages
(and the coYoneda lemma in category theory)?

Related links:

1. The relationship between closure conversion and coYoneda: http://prl.ccs.neu.edu/blog/2017/08/28/closure-conversion-as-coyoneda/
2. The relationship between CPS translation and double-negation translation:

   - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411599/how-is-the-double-negation-translation-similar-to-cps-in-functional-programming
   - Noam Zeilberger's thesis (in a polarized setting) http://noamz.org/thesis.pdf

Comment: Could you add some links or references, e.g. for the coYoneda lemma and CPS style? Peirce's Law might be a more familiar reference point for some.

Comment: @MarkWildon eg CPS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style ; co-Yoneda https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Yoneda+lemma

Comment: Roughly, and informally, it should say that if in the proof of a theorem concerning object $X$ you have a lemma concerning another object $Y$ which also refers to $X$ (i.e., the setup of the theorem), you can avoid this by stating an independent lemma which concerns pairs $(X,Y)$ (satisfying various conditions, of course).

Comment: (But in practice this doesn't seem too important because in normal mathematical style we often leave it to the reader to figure out what objects a result is being applied to, so we don't even really distinguish a partial closure.)